# How to save pictures that are linked externally, in a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with pictures that are linked externally.

To save the pictures in the document I hit `Alt + F9` by `Office-->Prepare-->Edit links to file-->Save Picture in document`.

How do I handle this in a VBA macro?

Comment: Hi Portland Runner, Thank you. The link you shared all about save the pictures from the document to separate folder. My requirement is to save the linked images into the document.

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder? If so, please post the code and explain what it doesn't do or should do differently.

Comment: I tried with macro recorder but it doesn't record anything, just showing empty sub.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this feature (it looks like it was active in earlier versions of Word but hidden in 2010, which is what I have). But this seems to get at its functionality. Try this:

```
Sub SaveLinkedPictures()

Dim objDoc As Document
Dim objShape As InlineShape

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

    For Each objShape In objDoc.InlineShapes
        objShape.LinkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = True
    Next objShape

End Sub
```

Is that what you're after? One thing to always try when macro recorder comes up empty is the Object Browser (from within the VBE, View > Object Browser). You can search for what you think a command or object might be called (in this case "link" or "savepicture"). It can help get closer when you don't know where to start.